# PHP when executing bat file display command prompt window on server?

Tags: php, apache, batch-file, minecraft

I've setup a webpage that will allow me to remotely execute the bat file that I use to start my minecraft server in case I want to play while away. I have successfully managed to run the bat file and start the server remotely from my site, however there is no visual display of the command prompt on the server (My desktop) as there generally is when a bat file is normally run. Because of this, I am unaware of a good way to stop my server.

Is there any way to have the command prompt display itself on the server when the bat file is run remotely using PHP? Is anyone aware of any *simple* way that I can run commands on the server through the website, just as I would if I were using command prompt?

My website is run using wamp (apache) on the same desktop as the server, I change the directory to the location of the bat file and am able to execute it.

Here's my website code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
echo getcwd() . "\n";
chdir('C:\wamp\www\MinecraftServer');
exec('server.bat', $output);
echo implode("\n", $output);
}
?>
<!doctype http>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Index </title>
        <style>
        body {background-color: GREENYELLOW}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Welcome! </h1>
        <h2> Are you here looking for the minecraft map? Click <a href="./WorldMap/map.html"> here </a>.</h2>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="button">Start Server</button>
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4096M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.exe nogui
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

- Can you please share your ***.bat***? Maybe it's simply not producing any output?
- Can you var_dump the ***$output***? When array is empty, no matter what the glue is, ***implode*** will output empty string as far as I remember.
- If you want to make newlines in the browser you shall use `<br/>` tag, so your echo shall look like this:
  `echo nl2br(implode("\n", $output));`
  or
  `echo implode("<br/>", $output);`
- And you have wrong tag in your HTML markup, change `http` to `html`
- Have you tried backicks only?
- You may want to consider output the result of executing ***.bat*** to some text file and then read the contents of that file.
- Use `@ECHO OFF` in your ***.bat*** to prevent cluttering the output

Comment: The bat file's nothing special, it simply runs the minecraft server. Usually running this from the desktop brings up command prompt:


"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4096M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.exe nogui
pause


When I press the button, the server starts and is accessible by typing in the ip. However, usually to stop the server I just type "stop" into the command prompt window that the bat file starts. However, no command prompt window appears when starting it with PHP, so I have no way of stopping or interacting with the server remotely or via my desktop.

Comment: Sorry, realized line spacing doesn't work in comments. Added bat file to main post.

Answer (score 0):

The [popen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) function can help you, it opens a pipe to a process executed by forking the command given by command.

From [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php):

> ### popen
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5) popen — Opens process file pointer
>
> ### Description
>
> `resource popen ( string $command , string $mode )`
>
> Opens a pipe to a process executed by forking the command given by command.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> command The command
>
> mode The mode
>
> ### Return Values
>
> Returns a file pointer identical to that returned by fopen(), except
> that it is unidirectional (may only be used for reading or writing)
> and must be closed with pclose(). This pointer may be used with
> fgets(), fgetss(), and fwrite(). When the mode is 'r', the returned
> file pointer equals to the STDOUT of the command, when the mode is
> 'w', the returned file pointer equals to the STDIN of the command.
>
> If an error occurs, returns FALSE.